# Adding new instructions to binutils 2.25

Tags: c, x86, binutils

I am new to binutils development. I am trying to add a new custom instruction that takes two operands (size, base virtual address) . I am using binutils 2.25.The opcode is 3 byte long and I am running it on x86 machine.Here is what I did :

1. Used i386-opc.tbl to add an entry as follows.

enclsecreate, 2, 0x0f01cf, None, 3, Cpu386, No_bSuf|No_wSuf|No_lSuf|No_sSuf|No_qSuf|No_ldSuf, {Reg64, Reg64}

My understanding,The second operand states the number of operands, followed by the opcode, followed by None, followed by number of bytes in the opcode.

2. The use i386-gen :

./i386-gen --srcdir=
which creates i386-tbl.h

3. i386-gen was not built, i built using make i386-gen and then ran the above step.
4. To enable the use of disassembler, we need to update  i386-dis.c.We need to add an entry to an table.I am lost at this point as to which table I need to add as there are so many of them and I dont understand the format of them.

It would be great if someone could guide me through further steps I need to take or point me to some documentations that contains the necessary information.Looking forward to your kind help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could have showed the actual encoding for this instruction as it is not yet in the official intel instruction set reference (january 2015 version).
I find it strange that you say it has 2 operands, because I don't see a place for encoding them (maybe they are implicit). So I'll just assume no operands for the following.

The comment at the top of `i386-dis.c` says:

> /* The main tables describing the instructions is essentially a copy
>   of the "Opcode Map" chapter (Appendix A) of the Intel 80386
>   Programmers Manual.  Usually, there is a capital letter, followed
>   by a small letter.  The capital letter tell the addressing mode,
>   and the small letter tells about the operand size.  Refer to    the
>   Intel manual for details.  */

The applicable table of the manual for your opcode is *Table A-6. Opcode Extensions for One- and Two-byte Opcodes by Group Number*. If you have an updated copy, you should find your instruction in the `0F 01 11B` row, column `001` with low 3 bits of `(111)`. This is of course the breakdown of the `CF`.

The first thing for binutils is the `0F 01` group and the `001` column. This means you have to edit the table `RM_0F01_REG_1`. That lists the 8 possible instructions in order of their low bits. My copy currently has `monitor` and `mwait` there, for `000` and `001` respectively. You might have others too. Since the low 3 bits of our new instruction are `111` which is `7` in decimal, it has to go in the last slot in that table. Pad the table with `Bad_Opcode` as necessary, then insert the new entry.

If you need special decoding of the operands, you can add a new function to handle it. Use an existing one (e.g. `OP_Monitor`) as template. By the way, it's also an easy way to locate the required table: just look for an existing instruction that is in the same encoding group as your new instruction.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   0f 01 cf                enclsecreate
```

Yay, success!

Comment: Thanks a lot.It helped me to understand much better now. But I required the instruction to mandatory contain two operands.So, it would be great if you could give directions as how to proceed in that case. Basically my requirement is whenever processor encounters this instruction, it should find address in one register and size in another.If I assume implicit operands, then what changes I need to perform in QEMU (the environment where I am emulating the new cpu).If not, what changes needs to be performed? To make things easy, it will be better if I have two operands to this instruction.

Comment: Can you also post your test program that u used in this case?

Comment: If the operands are implicit, then for emulating you should automatically use the implicit operands too. If you want to change `qemu` ask a separate question because that doesn't have much to do with `binutils`. The test program I used was just a `.byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xcf` to see that it gets disassembled correctly.

Comment: Thanks.I created a test program #include<stdio.h> int main() { __asm__("enclsecreate"); } I then compiled the program using the gcc with the binutils modifications that you suggested. It says no such instruction :enclsecreate. Any idea here will help me out immensely.

Comment: Well, your question specifically asked which table to edit for *disassembly*, so I assumed you got the assembly direction already working.

Comment: Doing what you did works here. You should of course make sure your `gcc` is using the `as` executable you just built. The encoding itself may be wrong, since you haven't provided that information. But the instruction is recognized and assembles with 2 operands (since you specified `Reg64`, `Reg64` in the table).

Comment: Problem seems to be that gcc is not using the assembler that I modified. Asbefore, I modified just the two files, "i386-opc.tbl" and "i386-dis.c". The encoding is as I mentioned before "enclsecreate, 2, 0x0f01cf, None, 3, Cpu386, No_bSuf|No_wSuf|No_lSuf|No_sSuf|No_qSuf|No_ldSuf, {Reg64, Reg64}". Is this what you are talking about? I didnt modify any other thing. I just recompiled binutils,gcc. How do I make gcc use my version of assembler. In the cross-dir/bin/gcc --version is 4.9.0 & cross-dir/bin/as is 2.25.cross-dir is where I have my source codes installed and its showing the correct value

Comment: Any suggestion here would greatly help me out in debugging.

Comment: I tried the following : Instead of using my instruction, I just used an existing instruction in the binutils. Like "vmlaunch". The program compiles with no errors. I then changed just the name from "vmlaunch" to "myvmlaunch" in i386-opc.tbl and i386-dis.c file. recompiled the binutils after running the i386-gen script. Now when I try to compile my program using gcc, it says Assembler messages : no such instruction "myvmlaunch"  . Clearly I am missing a very minor step. But unable to figure out what.Can anyone please help me out as I am stuck at this point from past few days !!!

Comment: You are not running the binutils you compiled. I just did your steps in the question and it works.

Comment: Can you just post the command you used to use the binutils that you modified? (configure command that you used for both gcc/binutils)

Comment: When I compiled the gcc, I gave option as --with-binutils=/data/softwares-iso/binutils-2.25 . Do I need to give the path from where I built the binutils (/data/softwares-iso/binutils-build)?

Comment: I don't think that matters. That is just for the binutils to use while building `gcc`. You don't even need to compile `gcc`. You need to make sure it finds your `as` at runtime, though. That is as easy as doing `PATH=/data/softwares-iso/binutils-2.25:$PATH gcc ...`

Comment: As suggested by you, i added the path. Though I am able to compile and create a object file, now it comes with error as "this linker was not configured to use sysroots" ld returned exit 1 status when I try to create a.out file. Any idea here?

Comment: No worries, I fixed it by recompiling the binutils again with sysroot